# Select last stats from column for each unique stat from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge problem.
I need check last(actual) stats for column balance for each unique id. Table like:

```
time_created         ID  balance 
2014-11-12 17:54:24  76  150 
2014-11-12 17:54:41  76  280 
2014-11-14 18:13:28  15  390 
2014-11-14 18:14:09  26  760 
2014-11-14 18:14:53  98  89 
2014-11-16 18:08:00  76  13 
...                  ...
```

What do I need to do to resolve it?

Thank Yours!

Comment: This sounds a **very valid** question to me, because **historicization of data** is an essential issue for database and app design. Before upvoting it, I would like to know why it was downvoted? (answered somewhere else, insufficiently documented, etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

Self join version. The sub-query with `group by` returns each id with it's latest time_created value.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select id, max(time_created) as time_created
        from tablename
        group by id) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id and t1.time_created = t2.time_created
```

`IN` version:

```
select *
from tablename
where (id, time_created) IN (select id, max(time_created)
                             from tablename
                             group by id)
```

`NOT EXISTS` version:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id
                    and t2.time_created > t1.time_created)
```

Comment: No doubt a question of taste, but the third solution has merits from a conceptual viewpoint, because it it is the closest to human formulation ("give me the list of rows that that **don't have** a higher time_created for each specific id"). On second thought, I also like the second one because it is very structured ("give me the list of rows that **have** the highest time_created for each specific id") as it adds WHERE clause without changing a single character in the original query. The first solution uses a JOIN, so I would perhaps call it "messy".

Comment: If anyone has a view on efficiency between these 3 choices, I would be curious to know.